# Endogenous selection bias / d-separation in SEM (Structural Equation Modeling)

Tags: bias, structural-equation-modeling, misspecification

I am a psychology student and currently working on a paper about omitted-variable bias in structural equation modelling (SEM). I am trying to tie endogenous selection bias to parametric SEM to illustrate that including some variables into a model, if misspecified, may in-fact bias estimates.

What I am unsure about is whether endogenous selection bias applies to SEM in the way that I understand it, and if it does, how I can proof this.

I know that in regression analysis conditioning on a collider can lead to endogenous selection bias (Elwert & Winship, 2014). To illustrate what I mean with conditioning on a collider picture the following:

- The true causal structure that can be depicted as follows: $X \rightarrow Z \leftarrow Y$
- According to this, the true effect of X on Y, $\beta_{YX} = 0$, because the two variables are marginally independent.
- Z is a collider on the backdoor path between X and Y through Z.
- If we were trying to estimate the effect of X on Y, and regressed Y on X **and** Z (and therefore condition on the variable Z), we would obtain  $\hat\beta_{YX.Z} \neq 0$.

This, so far, makes intuitive sense to me. 
I would also apply same principle to SEM with, for example, Maximum Likelihood estimation. My problem is that I have to proof that this extends to parametric SEM. My statistics knowledge is mainly about application and I do not know how to go about confirming my intuition, let alone proof it.

Can anyone help me out or point me to resources that can help? Is my understanding wrong after all, and SEM does not encounter the issue of endogenous selection bias?

Thanks in advance!

Jona

Elwert, F., & Winship, C. (2014). Endogenous selection bias: The problem of conditioning on a collider variable. Annual review of sociology, 40, 31-53.

Comment: You can look at an SEM equation by equation and just use the standard results from regression. I don't think there's anything special about SEM that makes it more or less susceptible to bias due to confounding or selection. If every variable in the system is in the SEM, then every variable is conditioned upon, and no backdoor paths can remain open. One potential resource is [Pearl (2013)](http://doi.org/10.1515/jci-2013-0003).